# GROUP BY aggregates too much:((

Tags: sql, ms-access

I’ve been searching and searching for a solution to a problem that is simple, but my SQL knowledge just isn’t good enough. The problem is about `GROUP BY`.

I have a simple table with sales in a book store, let’s say on a given day. Each book sold has an ID, a title and a sales value (what the client paid at the counter). The table has a simple header, with 4 fields: the book ID, the book title, the time stamp, the sales value.

The analysis I need to perform is on the book ID, without duplicate values (so unique books). The problem is that a book can be sold at different prices, because the client could have a client card and gets a discount.

So imagine that the raw DB table shows (I ignore the time stamp, that shows the date):

```
Book A   1 piece  20 dollars
Book A   1 piece  19.5 dollars
Book A   1 piece  20 dollars
Book A   2 pieces 30 dollars
```

Now, it is clear that Book A sold in 5 units overall. It is also clear that the amount paid for them is 85.9 dollars. But I do not need an aggregation that tells me this information, but rather how many books were sold at what unique price. In this case, the query should give me:

```
Book A   2 pieces 20 dollars (2 copies of the book were sold at 20 dollars each)
Book A   1 piece  19.5 dollars
Book A   2 pieces 15 dollars
```

(alternatively I would be happy with the query returning the sales value not the unit price as in the example above, that is not an issue, the issue is the aggregation).

I tried:

```
SELECT [BOOK ID], SUM ([QUANTITY]) AS SALES_QUANT, SUM ([SALES VALUE]) AS SALES_VAL 
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [BOOK ID]
```

This query gives me one row:

```
Book A, 5 pieces, 85.9 dollars
```

...as opposed to the 3 rows I expected.

Comment: I removed the `vba` tag, as there is nothing in your question that relates to it.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the query is in VBA and it runs with a MS Access database, but indeed, it is about SQL.

Comment: Then it would be relevant to add the  `ms-access` tag, as that determines which flavor of SQL you work with.

Comment: *"It is also clear that the amount paid for them is 85.9 dollars."*: it is not that clear to me. Maybe 89.5?

Comment: I would put the unit price in the database instead of the sum of all sold books at a certain price. This will save you a lot of headaches. When the third book is sold at 15 dollars, how will you update the database? The 4th book etc.? It's much easier to calculate the sum of X sold books at Y price later when or if you need this information.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately this is how our DB is designed, I just read data from it and analyze. It is indeed annoying to have the quantity per item and the total value of the sale per item as opposed to the unit price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also group by the unit price which is equal to `[SALES VALUE] / [QUANTITY]`:

```
SELECT [BOOK ID], SUM([QUANTITY]) AS SALES_QUANT, [SALES VALUE] / [QUANTITY] AS SALES_VAL 
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [BOOK ID], ([SALES VALUE] / [QUANTITY])
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f800312b85964e3d5c0bc55a10ecd8c3)(for SQL Server but it is Standard SQL and works as it is for MS Access to).
Results:

```
> BOOK ID | SALES_QUANT | SALES_VAL       
> :------ | ----------: | :---------------
> Book A  |           2 | 15.00
> Book A  |           1 | 19.50
> Book A  |           2 | 20.00
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it works indeed. Grouping by [SALES VALUE]/[QUANTITY] seems to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your GROUP BY should be:

```
 GROUP BY [SALES VALUE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple levels of grouping to achieve the desired result. Try:

```
GROUP BY [BOOK_ID], [PRICE]
```